# Android Phonegap Build error when using Push plugins like OneSignal and Pushbots

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Every time I try to run a build via Phonegap using the OneSignal or Pushbot plugin i keep getting an error for the Android build. Everything is implemented as per instructions but something is not working out properly.

For example here is the Phonegap Buil log error of the most recent build I did after adding the OneSignal plugin:

```
FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

**What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.**

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /project/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/project/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
>     Error Code:
>       2
>     Output:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

**Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.**

```
   BUILD FAILED

   Total time: 1 mins 20.379 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

The following from your log file means that there are 2 or more plugins in your project that contain the Android Support Library v4 or v13.

```
Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
```

If you working on setuping up OneSignal in your Android app see the [OneSignal Cordova Troubleshooting](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-common-problems) section for a list a plugins that are know to create conflicts and how to update to them to more compatible versions.